# How to patent a technology as public domain?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, open-source-software, patents, hardware

If an inventor comes up with a technology that could benefit humankind and instead of keeping it for themselves they decide they want to make it freely available to all, what would the legal process be for securing a patent for it that would make it public domain (like open source software, but for technologies that could be patented)?

And how can this be made to be honored internationally, so that no individual or company can claim ownership of it? That is to say, any individual or company can *use* it because nobody can *own* it.

Tesla is said to have "open sourced" some of its patents. But after taking [A Closer Look at Tesla’s Open-Source Patent Pledge](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=ca6c332f-2cc5-401b-b80d-36473d0754c7), it seems it is instead pledging not to bring lawsuits against companies that infringe on those patents. This is of course not quite the same thing as making the patents public domain.

So now I am wondering: **Is there any way to legally declare a technology as belonging to everyone?**

It occurred to me that maybe the [Creative Commons licenses](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/) are flexible enough to be used for technologies as well, but I'm not certain. I've only seen those licenses used for creative works, and since no filing is required, the process seems a bit different than the patenting process for technologies.

Answer (score 2):

### Publish it

Once an invention is in the public sphere it is ineligible to be patented.

Comment: Is that upheld in all countries? Also, as a way of explicitly letting others know it is not patented and free to use, is it best to somehow mark it, for example as CC-0, or perhaps simply with the words "public domain"?

Comment: @Dale M That is true after all grace periods have expired. An invention can be published and then a patent application can be filed in the U.S. up to a year later.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite yes, but only by the inventor who, in this case, wants it to not be patented so would not file a patent

Comment: @Mentalist other than during a statutory grace period no country allows patenting something that has been published. As a practical matter the patent examiner needs to find the publication in their search. An obscure publication might not be found.

Comment: @DaleM - A third party doesn't know that the inventor intends not to patent it and therefore would need to wait until the year is up.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite So the answer is: in order to reduce the likelihood of someone falsely registering a patent during the statutory grace period, the originator of the invention should very publicly publish it, and clearly mark it as "public domain". Would that be correct?

Comment: @Mentalist - If the publication is prominent enough or brought to the attention of the examiner, a third party should not be able to get a patent. I do NOT think the inventor labeling something as public domain would prevent the inventor from changing their mind and filing. It might make it harder from them to actually use any resulting patent to go after someone who relied on that statement. A third party who incorporated the invention into a product would be advised to monitor patent application publications and granted patents by the inventor.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Hopefully any patent examiner reviewing the application, upon finding the publicly published record of the invention labeled "public domain", would reject it. Part of their duty as an examiner is to ensure patents are legitimately registered to the rightful patent owner, but not anyone falsely claiming to be. Being published marked "public domain" should signify the intention of the inventor to share it. In the rare case that the inventor changes their mind and later wants to claim the patent, I expect they would need to prove they invented and published it. Don't you think so?

Comment: If an examiner finds something published during the grace period that wasn't clearly by the inventors they would issue a rejection and it would be up to the applicant to establish that it is by the inventors or taken from the inventors and published by someone else. The standard of proof would not be high. In any case the label "I'm putting this is in the public domain" would not be partially relevant.